# Using MSBuild to compile WPF User Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild

I am trying to use MSBuild to compile WPF user controls into a library. In a test project I get the results I expected to, however in my active project I have run into nothing but problems.

This being the first time I have used MSBuild I created a test project to figure out how to use it. I added references to Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Engine, using the code below my program did exactly what I wanted. The library compiled and I was able to load and use the usercontrol as intended.

**MSBuild C#**

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
namespace MSBuildTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\...\MSBuildTest.proj";
            ProjectCollection buildEngin = new ProjectCollection();
            Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
            GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");
            BuildRequestData BuildRequest = new BuildRequestData(fileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
            var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(buildEngin);
            BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, BuildRequest);
        }
    }  
}
```

**.proj file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>someoutputpath</OutputPath>
    <Assembly>MSBuildTest.dll</Assembly>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>  
    <Page Include="C:\...\UserControl1.xaml" />  
    <Compile Include="C:\...\UserControl1.xaml.cs" >
    <DependentUpon>UserControl1.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MsbuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**UserControl .xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"  />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TextBlock1"  Background="White" Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBlock2, Path=Text}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="Test" Background="White" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl .cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UserControlTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This worked");
        }
    }
}
```

I switched over to my main program to start implementing my new toy. I followed the same steps I did in my test project. I ran the program expecting it to work exactly as the test program had, but I got this exception:

> "System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies cannot be
> loaded for execution. (0x80131058)'"   I compared the projects and
> found that the test project I started was targeting .NET Framework
> 4.7.2 while my main project targeted .NET 7.0.

After research I found that with .Net 7.0 I should be using the MSBuild NuGet Package instead of referencing the MSBuild dlls.
So, I made the appropriate changes to my projects and tried running it again. The build fails and I get this exception:

> The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

More digging and I find that setting the "MSBuildSDKsPath" environment variable allows MSBuild to find the SDK. But the build fails again
with this exception:

> “The imported project
> "…MainProgram\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"
> was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "…MainProgram\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"
> is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props”

Setting the "AlternateCommonProps" environment variable appropriately
solved that problem, but:

> “The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified
> could not be found.  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props”

Given that I wasn’t making much progress this way I decided to try out
the Microsoft.Build.Locator. I made the appropriate changes to my
program. Using the locator, the program correctly finds the SDK
without having to set environments variables, which is nice. However,
my builds still fail and now all the exceptions are blank. I added a
logger to see if I can figure out what is going on.  Below are some of
the warnings and errors I received and through changes to the .proj
file was able to get past with varying degrees of success.

> Project "MSBuiltTest.proj" (Build target(s)): Warning C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3):
> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft.Common.targets" cannot
> be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets
> (327,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent
> import will be ignored. […\MSBuiltTest.proj] Done building project
> "MSBuiltTest.proj" -- FAILED.
>
> Project "MSBuiltTest.proj" (Build target(s)):
> GetReferenceAssemblyPaths: : ERROR C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1229,5):
> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not
> found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
> Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
> download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks Project "MSBuiltTest.proj"
> (Build target(s)):    ResolveAssemblyReference: : Warning C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352,5):
> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
> "System". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this
> reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …"WindowsBase"…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" PresentationCore "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" PresentationFramework "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" PresentationFramework "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" System.Xaml "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : Warning C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352,5):
> No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System".
> Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …"WindowsBase, …
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" PresentationCore "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" PresentationFramework "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" PresentationFramework "…
> ResolveAssemblyReference: : …" System.Xaml "… Done building project
> "MSBuiltTest.proj" -- FAILED.
>
> Project "MSBuiltTest.proj" (Build target(s)): ERROR C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(211,9):
> The "MarkupCompilePass1" task was not given a value for the required
> parameter "Language". Done building project "MSBuiltTest.proj" --
> FAILED.

The test project I built worked exactly as I had hoped it would, but my main program is continuously giving me grief. It’s my hope that I am missing some simple solution to my problems. But I have read everything I can find on how to use MSBuild, I have followed the endless rabbit trails of .common and .prop files and have even spent time digging through the MSBuild source code. The conclusion I have come to is that it’s turtles all the way down. Can someone tell me what I am missing or point me in the direction of some documentation that can help?

Comment: Does your project build in visual studio? That uses msbuild.

Comment: System.BadImageFormatException means that you're mixing 32bit and 64bit, which you can't do.

Comment: @Andy The project builds just fine in Visual Studios.

Comment: @user20716902 I came to the same conclusion and that is why I switched to using the Nuget Package.